# Populating Word2013 with XML data

Tags: xml, ms-word

This year I have to keep a log book of meetings with a tutor at university.

I'd like a word document that can take the data from the meetings stored in XML and insert it into the word document and format it in a way a define.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<logbookEntry>
    <date>02-09-2013</date>
    <Todo>
    thisandthat
    thisandthat
    thisandthat
    </todo>
    <notes>
    morenotes
    </notes>
</logbookEntry>
```

Is there a way I can set up a Word 2013 document to take multiple logbook entries and add them one after another into the document with some formatting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use content control databinding; in Word 2013 this can handle repeating data.